# Always get 400 error when using API POST to an ASP.net controller from a React

Tags: asp.net, react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NetCore 5 Entity Framework to search in my data.

When I post the data, I get a 400 error from the api
myController:

```
public IActionResult Search( [FromBody]string data)
```

my react:

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            searchTitle: this.state.searchTitle,
            boolTitle: this.state.boolTitle,
            boolSubject:this.state.boolSubject,
            searchElement:this.state.searchElement,
            refrence:this.state.refrence,
            maker:this.state.maker,
            subject:this.state.subject,
            startTimeArea:this.state.startTimeArea,
            endTimeArea:this.state.endTimeArea,
            type:this.state.type,
            isAvtive:this.state.isAvtive,
            enacmentTime:this.state.enacmentTime
        });
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
        'Accept':'application/json'
      }
    axios.post('/api/searchPost/search',data,{
        headers: headers
      }).
      then(result => console.log(result)).
      catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I try change [fromBody] to [fromForm] 400 error Fixed but receive value in controller string is null

Comment: Can you post your whole action code pls?

Comment: I edited qusetion my fatal problem is this

Comment: @roar s, check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this answer was first accepted, then it was not accepted. When looking into this again, it turns out that OP has changed the question without any notice, hence this answer doesn't line up with the question anymore.

The problem here is that this payload

```
{ searchTitle:this.state.searchTitle }
```

doesn't match the API controller method signature. You'll have to do it like this:

```
axios.post('/api/searchPost/search', JSON.stringify(this.state.searchTitle), {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}})
```

And you'll need to have the controller method signature like this:

```
public IActionResult Search([FromBody]string searchTitle)
```

Tested and verified with an asp.net Core 5 API and Postman.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked properly. Now how do you think I can send some data?  If you pay attention to the React code, there is some data in the data variable, all of which must be posted to the api