# get 400 error when using API POST to controller in React

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am using .NetCore 5 Entity Framework to search in my data.

When I post the data, I get a 400 error from the api
myController:

```
public IActionResult Search( [FromBody]string data)
```

my react:

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            searchTitle: this.state.searchTitle,
            boolTitle: this.state.boolTitle,
            boolSubject:this.state.boolSubject,
            searchElement:this.state.searchElement,
            refrence:this.state.refrence,
            maker:this.state.maker,
            subject:this.state.subject,
            startTimeArea:this.state.startTimeArea,
            endTimeArea:this.state.endTimeArea,
            type:this.state.type,
            isAvtive:this.state.isAvtive,
            enacmentTime:this.state.enacmentTime
        });
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
        'Accept':'application/json'
      }
    axios.post('/api/searchPost/search',data,{
        headers: headers
      }).
      then(result => console.log(result)).
      catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I try change [fromBody] to [fromForm] 400 error Fixed but receive value in controller string is null

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has asked the same question before. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321589/14072498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I post the data, I get a 400 error from the api myController:

> public IActionResult Search( [FromBody]string data)

To make HTTP request with data and make it bind to a string-type action parameter, you need to implement and use a custom plain text input formatter, like below.

```
public class TextPlainInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public TextPlainInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/plain");
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        string data = null;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        return InputFormatterResult.Success(data);
    }
}
```

*add custom formatter support*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddControllers(opt => opt.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new TextPlainInputFormatter()));
```

*update request headers on frontend*

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

axios.post('/api/searchPost/search', data, {
    headers: headers
}).
    then(result => console.log(result)).
    catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: I believe this is a X/Y question. OP thinks he needs a controller method with signature like in the question, while he really needs a controller method that accepts a DTO. BR